# Store listing is not activated in Google Play while trying to publish my app

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to publish my newly developed app in Google Play. I have done this earlier. In google developer console I have uploaded my app successfully and it is showing activated. But in the store listing I have filled all mandatory information, still it is not activated. I have attached a screen shot of the store listing page. There you can see on the screen shot that I have filled all mandatory fields. When I check "why I can't publish" menu on right most corner, it showing me "You need to add a title" and "You need to add a description". But I already filled those out. Does anyone have any idea on this?

[image]

Comment: If You added other languages, You have to fill all this stuff separately. Click "Languages" and check if other ones are enabled and check if You filled them too...

Comment: Did you fill this fields for all the languages you provided ?

Comment: let me try it. Why don't you post this as answer.

Comment: Thanks dude I solved it. It is for the different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You added other languages, You have to fill all this stuff separately. Click "Languages" and check if other ones are enabled and check if You filled them too...

Answer (score 10):

For me it was because I didn't have at least two screenshot images.

For others it may be different. You can hover your mouse over the grayed out checkbox to see what is still missing.

[image]